# React Native Expo audio player error - Player does not exist

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using react native expo audio in my app, I use createAsync to load the audio in the player but sometimes i get Player doesn't exist error and sometimes it works fine. I'm unable to debug the error.
I've also tried expo loadAsync to create and load the audio, it also produces the same error.
Heres my code...

```
    componentWillMount(){
        const audioFileLocation = audioFile;
        const source = audioFileLocation;
        const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
            source,
            {
                progressUpdateIntervalMillis: 1000,
                shouldPlay: false,
                isLooping: false,
            },
            onPlaybackStatusUpdate,
        );
        return sound;Ï
    }

export const playAndPauseSound = async (playbackStatus, playbackInstance) => {
    if (playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
        await playbackInstance.pauseAsync();
    } else {
        if (playbackStatus.positionMillis === playbackStatus.durationMillis) {
            return playbackInstance.replayAsync();
        } else {
            return playbackInstance.playAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on android when trying to play two sounds at the same time one fails with: 'Player doesn't exist' error.

Also I read somewhere that it helps to unload and load the sound from memory since after replaying a few times it can stop working.

See: [this link](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1873)